# asp.net :: J query :: add new element using J query

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I append new table cell to the page using c# and Jquery:

this code is in a web handler from that i called it from JQuery event  :

```
sb.Append("<td style=width: 5%; align=center>" + " <input id=cbSelect"+dt.Rows[i]["FileID"].ToString()+
                    " type=checkbox name=cbSelect"+dt.Rows[i]["FileID"].ToString()
                    +" onclick='return selectSingleCheckbox('"+dSize.ToString() +"','cbSelect"+dt.Rows[i]["FileID"].ToString()+"')';>"
                    + "</td>");
```

the table cell is add successfully, but it is java script  **`onclick='return selectSingleCheckbox('"+dSize.ToString() +"','cbSelect"+dt.Rows[i]["FileID"].ToString()+"')'`** doesn't fired.

How can I fire this javascript event according to the table cell

Comment: What does the output html look like?

Comment: <td style="width:" 5%;="" align="center"> <input id="cbSelect189" type="checkbox" name="cbSelect189" onclick="return selectSingleCheckbox(" 673','cbselect189')';=""></td>

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having an onclick property on the input you can do a method like this

```
$(document).live('click','input[id|="cbSelect"]',function() {
   ..
});
```

and use data-size and data-fileid attrubutes on input to store the values for input and use them in the function

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `onclick` there, put it in your included JavaScript file:

```
$(document).on('click', '[id^=cbSelect]', function () {
    return selectSingleCheckbox(673, 'cbselect189');
});
```

Comment: but I have multi cells every, and each of them has it is own parameters values

Comment: @RaedAlsaleh are the parameters somewhere else in the html, or are they only on the server?  You could store them on `data-` attributes on the input and access them that way

Comment: @RaedAlsaleh `.on` is only available in jQuery 1.7+.  If you can't upgrade to it, use `$(document).delegate('[id^cbSelect]', 'click', function () { ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can make each element individually:

```
var input = $('<input type="checkbox">');
var container = $('<div class="container"/>');

input.click(function(){
    // add your click event code here for the checkbox
});

// append input to container
container.append(input);
```

Just a quick example, i'm sure you can figure it out from here. It's nice having each element as an object and then append them into a structure.

Comment: but get all of the elements as an output from c#  web handler

Comment: build each element separately and put your click events on whatever objects. then append/prepend those objects into whatever structure you want.. the click events will be handled properly.